# How to concatenate rows with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, concatenation

Edited: In SQL, I’m joining a table with a text column to a separate table (the latter not depicted in my example below). I would like to display the text from each row concatenated as a single column in a row. Using a separate column (Line), I’d like to use to determine the order in which the text is concatenated.

```
Col   Line   Text
a     1      This
a     4      sentence
a     3      a
a     2      is
```

Output in a single column/row:

```
This is a sentence
```

Comment: Are you asking about SQL or some other language?  Is it a database or in-memory table of some sort?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY Line` to display the rows in the desired order, but it will take programming to concatenate the values of `Str` into a string.

Comment: Hi, it will be possible to help if you provide a language you are using and any extra details (e.g. things you have tried)

Comment: string aggregation differs depending on the DBMS. For example [MySql - GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), [Oracle DB - LISTAGG](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php), [Sql Server - STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql), [PostgreSql - STRING_AGG](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-string_agg-function/).  So knowing your DBMS & version might be helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in postgresql:

```
select  string_agg(Str,' ' order by Line ) as Sentence FROM Table1
group by Col;
```

Output:

```
sentence
This is a sentence
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e84f9/4

Answer (score 1):

In MySql try:

```
select  group_concat(Str order by Line separator ' ' ) as Sentence FROM Table1
group by Col;
```

Result:

```
sentence
This is a sentence
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e84f9e/5

Comment: Rofl, 2 answers for the price of one. Nice one.;)